# Creating a pandas DataFrame from a list followed by an array produces error

Tags: pandas, dataframe

When I try creating a pandas DataFrame with a list followed by an array, I get an error:

```
print(DataFrame([[10,20,30],np.arange(3)]))
```

TypeError: Expected list, got numpy.ndarray

But if I reverse the order of the data, then the operation succeeds:

```
print(DataFrame([np.arange(3),[10,20,30]]))
```

Could you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can give you a rough idea. There are multiple checks on data argument. If data argument is a list of items then the below code will execute under the hood. The first element of list is checked. If it's a list then it proceeds into listlike block but if its ndarray it proceeds into ndarray block. The lists block cannot handle ndarray but ndarray block can handle lists. This is why you don't get errors.

```
elif isinstance(data, (list, types.GeneratorType)):
    if isinstance(data, types.GeneratorType):
        data = list(data)
    if len(data) > 0:
-------> #IF FIRST ELEMENT IS LIST ENTER THIS BLOCK
        if is_list_like(data[0]) and getattr(data[0], 'ndim', 1) == 1:
            if is_named_tuple(data[0]) and columns is None:
                columns = data[0]._fields
            arrays, columns = _to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
            columns = _ensure_index(columns)

            # set the index
            if index is None:
                if isinstance(data[0], Series):
                    index = _get_names_from_index(data)
                elif isinstance(data[0], Categorical):
                    index = _default_index(len(data[0]))
                else:
                    index = _default_index(len(data))

            mgr = _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, columns,
                                 dtype=dtype)
------> #ELSE ENTER THIS BLOCK
        else:
            mgr = self._init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype,
                                     copy=copy)
    else:
        mgr = self._init_dict({}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. :)

Comment: Still, I am curious if it is logically (computer language theoretically) possible to allow the second syntax to mean the first one.

Comment: @Royalblue Didn't get you. Language is designed by humans, which will do exactly what it's told to. You can do anything within the scope of language rules.